# Did Zenitsu kill upper moon in awake mode?

Tags: demon-slayer

I did not read the manga, but i saw people share about this, I don't want any 'extra' spoiler regarding to this question, I just wanted to know if Zenitsu kill upper moon in Sleep mode or Awake mode,

If he is in awake mode, is he in 100% full capability skill just like he in Sleep mode?

Comment: He does later in the series and it will be Manga spoilers for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he is awake when he kills him.

This is shown in Chapter 144. [Link to picture](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Zenitsu_Agatsuma?file=Zenitsu_slashing_Kaigaku%2527s_neck.png)